# VB POST request whit form-control values

Tags: vb.net, api, post, visual-studio-2008

I am having different problems when trying to make a POST request to my API, the API works perfectly tested in postman.

I would like to know if anyone sees that I am doing wrong, thank you very much

```
    Dim url As String = "http://0.0.0.0/connect"
    Dim dataToPassFromFormData As String = "client_id=1020&client_secret=FF29D58E&grant_type=password&username=admin&password=123"
    Dim enc As UTF8Encoding
    Dim postdatabytes As Byte()
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = TryCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
    enc = New System.Text.UTF8Encoding()
    postdatabytes = enc.GetBytes(dataToPassFromFormData)
    request.Method = "POST"
    request.ContentLength = postdatabytes.Length

    Using stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        stream.Write(postdatabytes, 0, postdatabytes.Length)
    End Using

    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = TryCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    Dim receiveStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim readStream As StreamReader = New StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8)

    Dim us As user
    us = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of user)(readStream.ReadToEnd())
    response.Close()
    readStream.Close()
    Return us.access_token
```

My api expects these parameters by body / form-data

```
client_id=1020
client_secret=FF29D58E
grant_type=password
username=admin
password=123
```

Comment: Set `Option Strict On`, try to fix all the issues that come up; yes, almost every single line of it, but you'll begin to understand what's wrong (especially `Dim dataStream As String = s.GetResponse()`, then see what you're going to use `postdatabytes` for).

Comment: @Jimi yes i see meny erros , i update the code, still give me 400 code error

Comment: You haven't fixed all the errors Option Strict pointed you to. Anyway, it's just `s = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url)`. Now you have to add to your question what you're posting and what the remote endpoint is expecting to see (Encoding included). I.e., follow the instructions of: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), an information you should have gotten from the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Take  [theTour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) you skipped when prompted to.

Comment: @Jimi thnx u for the help, i change again the code... The api continue response 400 i thing i make evrything u say

Comment: You still have to post what *your API* is expecting to receive. Nobody knows but you.

Comment: @Jimi i added , sorry.

Comment: Those are just string values. Is the API expecting a form-urlencoded sequence of value pairs? Then try to set it: `request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`. You should also encode these values, see [WebUtility.UrlEncode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.urlencode) (except email addresses). But it may accept non encoded data anyway. Or is it something else?

Comment: @Jimi Hi, I put it down completely, working perfectly by POSTMAN. I send it by body / form-contro